# Delete all files in current directory with 2-character names using bash

Tags: linux

How do I issue a command under `bash`ro delete all files in current directory with 2-character names?

I've done every possible combinations I can think of:

```
rm -r ?? .
rm -r [??].
rm -r ??.
```

I'm not list the other ones I've come up with but I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: Is it just current directory or current directory and it's subdirectories?

Comment: Assuming you want to include subdirectories, I don't see much wrong with `rm -r ??`, apart from prompting: why do you say it doesn't work? And what do you want to happen with two-character directory names?

Answer (score 3):

I asked in a comment above if this was to remove two-character length filenames in the current directory or in the current directory AND subdirectories. I'll list both solutions here:

To delete files that have a 2-character length filename in the current directory

```
rm ??
```

To delete files that have a 2-character length filename in the current directory as well as subdirectories:

```
find . -name '??' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This one is a bit trickier since the filenames take on the path as you traverse through subdirectories. Instead of trying to figure this out with the `rm` command, we use `find` by name with the `??` for the 2 character wildcard and then use the `-exec` option to do the `rm` on whatever is found `{}`.

Comment: As long as you are confining find to the current directory you should be safe without a max depth (assuming you aren't sitting in root or home or somewhere else deep and scary) At least it's not as scary as running an `rm -rf /I/hope/I/dont/fat/finger/this`

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` with `exec`. First do a dry run like this to make sure you are not acting on things you don’t want to act on:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??' -exec ls -latr {} \;
```

Then when you are positive it works the way you wish, run this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Also, pay attention to `maxdepth`. That will contain your actions to just the current directory. Without `maxdepth` the `find` command will run rampant all over your system just doing whatever to two character filenames. Of course increase `maxdepth` to match whatever depth you want to go to, but remember that you run the risk of damaging your system if you do not use that and do some dry run tests on the `find` logic before running the `rm -rf`.

With GNU find (which is in most of Linux distributions) you can also use the option `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -rf {} \;`. `-delete` could be slightly more effective because it does not need to call an external command but it is not part of the POSIX specification.

Comment: @pabouk If we're going for POSIX compliance you should remove the `-maxdepth` too.